# MailChimp Dynamic Redirects After Submission

Tags: html, mailchimp

Is it possible to use dynamic "thank you" pages upon submission of a mailchimp opt-in form? I'm currently using the API and have single opt-in enabled.

Here's my situation.

I provide web design tutorials to my viewers, at the bottom of the tutorial I have an opt-in form that says "learn how to code this design in html". When a visitor subscribes I need to redirect them to the HTML tutorial.

It seems that the redirect code below doesn't work and MailChimp only let's you set a single thank you page per list on their website.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.somesite.com/somefile">
```

Is there anyway around this? My plan was to use custom fields in wordpress and manually enter the redirect url for each post but have found that this won't work.

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to accomplish the same thing (without buying leadpages)

Comment: I had to end up sending them to a landing page with all my videos. Sadly, I wasn't able to find a way to make the redirect dynamic.

Comment: I am looking now at the mailchimp API and probably going to hand code a 'subscribe form' that a) sends the data to mailchimp via the API, and then redirects the user to the appropriate bonus page. something like that